# Excel Split Data from 1 cell into multiple cells

Tags: excel, vba, split, cell

I have an excel macro that currently reads data from a single cell and hides/shows rows if that cells value is between a certain number.

What I am looking to do is add functionality to the macro so when that given cell reaches a certain value it shows/hides a row and then divides the original cells value by the number of rows shown and places an equal value in each of the rows.

So if G10 has a value of 2200, row H is unhid and then cell G10 becomes 1100 and H10 will become 1100 as well.

Here is my current code:

Edit: In each If statement I want to add something that will take cell.Value and divide it equally between the rows that are becoming unhidden in that if statement.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Set rng = Sheets("Summary").Range("G10:P10")

Application.EnableEvents = False

Sheets("Summary").Range("11:19, 23:31, 43:51, 54:62, 78:86, 90:98").EntireRow.Hidden = True

For Each cell In rng

    If cell >= 2000 And cell < 4000 Then
        Sheets("Summary").Range("11:11, 23:23, 43:43, 54:54, 78:78, 90:90").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Sheets("Summary").Range("12:19, 24:31, 44:51, 55:62, 79:86, 91:98").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

    If cell.Value >= 4000 And cell.Value < 6000 Then
        Sheets("Summary").Range("11:12, 23:24, 43:44, 54:55, 78:79, 90:91").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Sheets("Summary").Range("13:19, 25:31, 45:51, 56:62, 80:86, 92:98").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

    If cell.Value >= 6000 And cell.Value < 8000 Then
        Sheets("Summary").Range("11:13, 23:25, 43:45, 54:56, 78:80, 90:92").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Sheets("Summary").Range("14:19, 26:31, 46:51, 57:62, 81:86, 93:98").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

    If cell.Value >= 8000 And cell.Value < 10000 Then
        Sheets("Summary").Range("11:14, 23:26, 43:46, 54:57, 78:81, 90:93").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Sheets("Summary").Range("15:19, 27:31, 47:51, 58:62, 82:86, 94:98").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

    If cell.Value >= 10000 And cell.Value < 12000 Then
        Sheets("Summary").Range("11:15, 23:27, 43:47, 54:58, 78:82, 90:94").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Sheets("Summary").Range("16:19, 28:31, 48:51, 59:62, 83:86, 95:98").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

    If cell.Value >= 12000 And cell.Value < 14000 Then
        Sheets("Summary").Range("11:16, 23:28, 43:48, 54:59, 78:83, 90:95").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Sheets("Summary").Range("17:19, 29:31, 49:51, 60:62, 84:86, 96:98").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

    If cell.Value >= 14000 And cell.Value < 16000 Then
        Sheets("Summary").Range("11:17, 23:29, 43:49, 54:60, 78:84, 90:96").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Sheets("Summary").Range("18:19, 30:31, 50:51, 61:62, 85:86, 97:98").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

    If cell.Value >= 16000 And cell.Value < 18000 Then
        Sheets("Summary").Range("11:18, 23:30, 43:50, 54:61, 78:85, 90:97").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Sheets("Summary").Range("19:19, 31:31, 51:51, 62:62, 86:86, 98:98").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

    If cell.Value >= 18000 Then
        Sheets("Summary").Range("11:19, 23:31, 43:51, 54:62, 78:86, 90:98").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
Next

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What is your question ? Does your code work ? If not, what does it give as result ?

Comment: gives us a screenshot :)

Comment: The code works as it is but does not have the extra split value equally function I want. In each of those If statements I want to add something that will take the cell.Value and divide it equally between the rows that become unhidden.

Comment: I suggest you try to add the functionality you require and if it doesn't work, come back and ask how to fix it.

Comment: Thats just it, I dont know where to begin with that kind of functionality for vba, im more of a java coder.

Comment: You **will** run into recursion problems if the Calculation routine both uses and modifies G10 cell. Therefore, I would suggest that you perform this "splitting" of G10 value as a formula, not as part of the Calculation routine. Probably you should use two cells, one for the "user-entered" value, and one for the "split" value.

Comment: Yea I was thinking that I might have to add another cell for just the user data. I was trying something like Set Sheets("Summary").Range("G10:P10") = (cell.Value) / 2 in the if statement for between 2000 and 4000 but come up with a debug error. Is there a way to split and divide without vba so if a row is shown then it performs the calc

Comment: lol at the java coder.

Comment: Java Coder or VBA coder your logic is really bad. For one I've given you answer that already tells you a way to not have to loop through every single cell. Second, And this is EXACTLY the same logic as if it where in Java, instead of using multiple If's use is and else if. Also, for all Languages, if you started by testing the largest number first and worked down to the smallest number you wouldn't have to test EVERY value twice only once. example. If you test for >=1800 THEN >= 1600 and you have 1700 Then if it doesn't fire on >= 1800 then you know that it isn't and you wouldn't have to test

Comment: You should also, If you REALLY want to use a loop when you don't have to, you should have an exit clause for when a condition is meet. Second with this many conditions a `Select Case` would be much better then all the if's, in Java this would be the `Switch` function.

Comment: I put it in a for loop because its checking a range of cell value not just one cells value, I put this together just to get it to work right and was going to simplify it down after I got it functioning correctly and it wont be functioning correctly until I can get some sort of Set or Split or Divide function for each if case.

Comment: I am also planning to add a ClearContents line for each if so that if a user changes the input which in turn hides a row, the contents of that row will be cleared. which is why I cant hardcode in the cell this functionality and have to do it in vba.

Answer (score 0):

As a new column appears for each 2000 in G10, one can say:

```
columns_number = ceil(G10 / 2000)
```

Now, let's say the user enters the value in G9 instead of G10.

Let's say we use H9 as a placeholder for "columns_number": In H9 you write

```
 = CEILING(G9/2000;1)
```

Then, contents of G10 is trivial:

```
 = $H$9
```

And contents of H10:

```
 = IF($H$9>=2;$H$9;0)
```

And contents of I10:

```
 = IF($H$9>=3;$H$9;0)
```

...

and so on until P10.

Summary:

```
    G            H                    I
 9  2200         =CEILING(G9/2000;1)
10  =$H$9        = IF($H$9>=2;$H$9;0) = IF($H$9>=3;$H$9;0)
```

Comment: I was thinking of hardcoding into the cell but I am also planning to add a ClearContents line for each if so that if a user changes the input which in turn hides a row, the contents of that row will be cleared. which is why I cant hardcode in the cell this functionality and have to do it in vba.

Comment: You can combine ... add the clearcontent feature in your Calculate macro : `If Sheets("Summary").Cells("H10") = 0 Then Sheets("Summary").Range("H11:H").ClearContents` (adapt the range to your needs).

Answer (score 0):

Im really confused by your question based on you want to split out by rows, but then you use COLUMNS g and H as examples?? TRy this and see how it work for you.

***NOTE: ALWAYS RUN UNTESTED CODE ON A COPY OF YOUR WORKBOOK AND NEVER THE ACTUAL DATA***

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim TestValue As Integer, OffsetValue As Integer
Dim SplitValue As Double

Set rng = Sheets("Summary").Range("G10:P10")
Application.EnableEvents = False
Sheets("Summary").Range("11:19, 23:31, 43:51, 54:62, 78:86, 90:98").EntireRow.Hidden = True
TestValue = WorksheetFunction.Max(rng)

If TestValue >= 18000 Then TestValue = 18000

 OffsetValue = 9 - TestValue / 2000

 With Sheets("Summary").Range("11:" & 19 - OffsetValue & _
                              ", 23:" & 31 - OffsetValue & _
                              ", 43:" & 51 - OffsetValue & _
                              ", 54:" & 62 - OffsetValue & _
                              ", 78:" & 86 - OffsetValue & _
                              ", 90:" & 98 - OffsetValue)
      .EntireRow.Hidden = False
      .Value = TestValue / (.Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count / .Columns.Count)
 End With


Application.EnableEvents = True
```

This will get you the value that should be placed equally over the number of rows. I didn't finish because I am not sure if you really mean to use the word rows or columns in your question.